How to integrate ChemDoodle into a Nextjs app
Basically I am trying to setup ChemDoodle in my website. I followed the official tutorial of making it in reactjs: tutorial. And additionally, they provide a great demo on github. I tried with that repo and it works as expected. But my problem is that most of my website is currently built with nextjs. Even though I followed nextjs' tutorial of how to upgrade from reactjs to nextjs, the project doesn't work and I consistently get error such as "'ChemDoodle' not defined" or "'ChemDoodle' has been declared".
I am asking to see if any one can help or maybe explain detail about migrating from reactjs to nextjs regarding external js libraries.

Note: I also learned about next/dynamic, but as I am new to nextjs, I didn't quite get it.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.
This is the github repo that I followed to integrate ChemDoodle with reactjs, it works perfect for me.
But it doesn't work any longer if I create-next-app and import "react-chemdoodle" which results in "ChemDoodle not defined".
